# Is there function like parseInt() or parseFloat() but with a letter?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I want function like parseInt() or parseFloat(), but it will output letter. In better option it will output only first letter. Like this:

```
var text = Hello World!
var newval = parseLetter(text);
Output: H
```

Comment: use this `text[0]` is it what you need?

Comment: If you are just interested in first letter, you can use `str.charAt(0)`

Comment: There is your answer [by the link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp) :)

Comment: Thanks @xyz and @omegastripes! Working nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
function parseLetter(letter){
    return letter.charAt(0);
}
```

It will return the first letter of your string

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the first letter of your string as your output. Isn't it?
If That is the case, try the following..,

```
var text = "Hello World!"
var newval = text.charAt(0);
```